# access combine multiple fields and pivot it

Tags: ms-access, pivot, ms-access-2013

Table `Motor`
`MotorID, MotorType, FuelType, Contact, Dept<br>
AutoNum,  word,      word,     word,    word
1         PV         Petrol    Tony     FMO
2         LGV        Diesel    Mary     CLS`

Table `MotorRecord`
`MotorID, RecordDate, Amount
AutoNum,  Date,       Num
1         1/6/2013    2323
2         1/6/2013    2333`

Table `MotorType`
`MotorType, FuelType, CO2
word,       word,     Num
PV          Petrol    23
LGV         Diesel    34`

And my intended outcome looks like:
[image: sample]
Or a query/report(either is ok)
`PV Petrol Tony     LGV Diesel Mary
 Month    Amount    CO2   Amount   CO2
 Jul      2323     53429  2333    79322`

It seems pivot is my option but i am not familiar with the function.
You can assume the "2013-13" year label, Amount and CO2 do not need to exist.
I can add it back.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I see your query, but I don't see an attempt of Pivoting it. I understand you want help, and when I wrote my first one I wanted help, too. But, you need to give it an effort so people can have somewhere to begin. Just shipping a `SELECT` with a question doesn't do much for us.

Comment: @MarkC.Thanks. Let me try to edit the question.

Comment: @MarkC. Why i think pivot is needed is because i list motor details in column form